# Disabling UART Debug Serial Port on Linux

Tags: linux, uart

I am working on freescale imx8 board, where the we need to use the same UART for multiple purposes. By default this UART is configured as debug port as a console.

I have disabled this by modifying boot args (console = null from console = /dev/ttyLP0). I am checking the UART controller by running basic UART test using SSH, it is failing.

What can be the problem, do i need to do any modifications in kernel like disabling CONFIG_SERIAL_CONSOLE etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel boot argument `console` affects to output of kernel.

So, setting `console = null` in boot arguments won't prevent programs to use of the UART.

For example your `/etc/inittab` may contain the following kind of line for enabling logins via the UART:

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyLP0 vt100
```

There are ways to solve the problem:

1. Don't use the UART from any programs (For example: remove getty line from inittab)
2. Don't even create the serial device (/dev/ttyLP0).

Comment: Thank You for replying, how can i stop from creating /dev/ttyLP0. As i need to use the same for other purpose like modbus.

Comment: What will happen if i disable  CONFIG_SERIAL_CONSOLE in linux kernel. I want to access console using SSH, but not through UART

Comment: @anikhan  CONFIG_SERIAL_CONSOLE affects only for kernel.
SSH uses TCP/IP, so I assume that ssh-clients connect to ssh-server of your board via some network interface (ethernet, wlan, LTE, whatever). Right?  In that case disabling an UART should not be a problem for SSH.